# R file gets deleted after adding a new Activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I know that this question has been asked before but trust me, I have tried every single solution suggested in the prior posts. Here's the error that I am getting form the gradle console:

```
res\menu\final.xml:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**What went wrong:**

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:    C:\Program
> >     Files\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package -f
> >     --no-crunch -I C:\Program Files\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M
> >     C:\Users\bang\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
> >     -S C:\Users\bang\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\res\debug
> >     -A C:\Users\bang\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug
> >     -m -J C:\Users\bang\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\generated\source\r\debug
> >     -F C:\Users\bang\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\libs\app-debug.ap_
> >     --debug-mode --custom-package bang.myproject -0 apk Error Code:   1 Output:   res\menu\final.xml:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'

Now, it kind of looks like that there is a problem in final.xml file, which is auto generated. 
Here it is if you want to take a look at it as well:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="bang.MyProject.FinalActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

This has to do with the R class because the R class is deleted after adding a new activity. So, all the places where I am using `R.id`... have a red line underneath it.

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Clean and rebuild project.
2. Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files
3. Close and open android studio

Comment: what this have to do with `r`?

Comment: Stop with "r" tag, please.

Comment: @Pgibas, please read my post again. I have added the explanation as to why R tag is needed.

Comment: @bangbang Do you know about what is the "r" tag?

Comment: The R being red can just mean that your project didn't compile correctly for a completely other reason. as you noted, it gives an error that points to Output: res\menu\final.xml:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'. It might be that the word 'final' is a protected word. try refactoring the menu to be called something else.

Comment: @Michael Alan Huff, thank you. That was the issue.

Comment: @Pascal, I thought it stands for the R class in android. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R being red can just mean that your project didn't compile correctly for a completely different reason. As you noted, it gives an error that points to Output: res\menu\final.xml:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'. It might be that the word 'final' is a protected word. Try refactoring the menu to be called something else.

For a list of protected words, see this post. [List of reserved words in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912802/list-of-reserved-words-in-android)